# Flutter disable scrolling on CupertinoNavBar with large title

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

How can I disable scrolling when there is a widget with CupertinoNavBar and large title? For instance I have:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled){
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Settings'),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Center(child: Text('Home Page'),),
      ),
    );
  }
```

if I add  `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` it doesn't work